# Why class want instance, but i don't use it?

Tags: class, system-verilog

I have 2 interfaces:

```
interface IAvsBus(input bit clk);
    bit [15:0] wraddr, rdaddr;
    bit [31:0] wrdata;
    logic [31:0] rddata;
    bit write, read;
endinterface

interface ISpi();
    logic sclk, csn, mosi, miso;
endinterface
```

And 2 classes with interfaces:

```
class AvsBus;
    virtual IAvsBus bus;

    function new(virtual IAvsBus bus);
        this.bus = bus;
    endfunction

    task automatic Write(int unsigned addr, int unsigned data);
...
    endtask

    task automatic Read(int unsigned addr, output int unsigned data);
...
    endtask
endclass :AvsBus

class SpiBus;
    virtual ISpi spi;

    function new(virtual ISpi spi);
        this.spi = spi;
        this.spi.sclk = 0;
        this.spi.csn = 1;
        this.spi.mosi = 1;
    endfunction

    task WriteSingle(input shortint addr, input int data, output bit result);
...
    endtask

    task ReadSingle(shortint unsigned addr, output int unsigned read_data, output bit result);
...
    endtask
endclass :SpiBus
```

And common class which uses one of them in testbench:

```
class Task;
...
    task Write(ref AvsBus bus);
...
    endtask

    task SpiWrite(ref SpiBus spi);
...
    endtask
endclass :Task
```

If I comment out the unused class and unused task from the common class, then all work. It does not work if both exist. ModelSim throws an error, such as:

> Virtual interface resolution cannot find a matching instance for 'virtual IAvsBus'

Answer (score 0):

This was a problem with older versions of Questa/Modelsim. The compiler still needs to generate the code for the tasks that use the virtual interface variable and has no way of knowing they will never be called. Usually the choice is made by how +UVM_TESTNAME os set at run-time. This is a problem especially when the interface is parameterized.